# Hangman game in Python - my break seems to only work every OTHER time the game is played

Tags: python, function, break, game-loop

as the title suggests, the game works fine, but it seems I've got a bug that I cannot figure out.

After the first game, when it asks if you'd like to play again, it proceeds with the next game just fine, you can play that one, then finally after that game, it doesn't ask if you want to play again, but starts a new game automatically, with the word that just happened in the previous one.

I can't figure out if it is my play_again function or my check_win function or what.

thanks for any help

```
import random

def main():

    hangman_word = generate_random()

    while True:
        play_game(hangman_word)

        if play_again() == 2:
            return False
            break
        else:
            hangman_word = generate_random()            
            play_game(hangman_word)


############################################
# The game!
############################################

def play_game(random_word):

    clear()
    guesses = ""
    tries = 9

    while True:
        winning_number = 0
        hangmanInterface(tries)
        print("WORD:", end="")
        for char in random_word:
            if char in guesses:
                print(" {} ".format(char), end="")
            else:
                print(" _ ", end="")
                winning_number += 1

        if win_check(winning_number, tries) == True:
            break

        print_x(1)

        print("    Tried:", end="")
        for j in range(len(guesses)):
            print("[{}]".format(guesses[j]), end="")
        spacing_fix(2)
        guess = get_guess()
        guesses += guess

        print_x(2)

        if guess not in random_word:
            tries -= 1
    return
##########################################


##########################################
# generates a random word
##########################################
def generate_random():

    #opens the dictionary and initializes a random word
    with open("dict.txt") as fp:
        dictwords = []
        for line in fp:
            dictwords.append(line.rstrip("\n"))

    #makes sure the word is in lower case        
    rand = random.choice(dictwords)
    randlower = rand.lower()
    return randlower


##########################################





##########################################
# Checks if the game should restart
##########################################
def play_again():

    print("Play again?")
    print("1. yes!")
    print("2. no :(")
    ans = get_ans()
    return ans

##########################################
def get_ans():
    ans1 = input()
    ans = int(ans1)
    if ans == 1 or ans == 2:
        return ans
    else:    
        print("Please type 1 or 2")
        get_ans()

##########################################





##########################################
# checks for the win
########################################## 
def win_check(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        print_x(2)
        print("######################")
        print("#                    #")
        print("#    W I N N E R     #")
        print("#                    #")        
        print("######################")        
        return True
    elif b == 0:
        print_x(2)
        print("######################")
        print("#                    #")
        print("#     L O S E R      #")
        print("#                    #")        
        print("######################")  
        return True
##########################################   




##########################################
# gets users guess while ensuring only
# one alpha, lowercase char is entered
########################################## 
def get_guess():
    get = input("    Guess: ")
    a = get.lower()
    if len(a) > 1:
        print("One letter only")
        get_guess()
    elif not a.isalpha():
        print("One letter only")
        get_guess()

    return a
##########################################   




##########################################
# Aesthetic Functions
##########################################
def clear():
    for i in range(25):
        print ('\n')

#########################
def print_x(x):
    for i in range(x):
        print("\n")


#########################
def spacing_fix(tmp):
    if tmp == 0:
        tmp = 1
        return tmp
    if tmp == 2:
        print()
        tmp = 3
        return tmp
##########################################


##########################################
# prints board state
########################################## 
def hangmanInterface(index):
        if index==0:
            clear()
            print('          _____ ')
            print('          |   | ')
            print('          O   | ')
            print('         /|\  | ')
            print('         / \  | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('      ________|_')
            return
        if index==1:
            clear()
            print('          _____ ')
            print('          |   | ')
            print('          O   | ')
            print('         /|\  | ')
            print('         /    | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('      ________|_')
            return
        if index==2:
            clear()
            print('          _____ ')
            print('          |   | ')
            print('          O   | ')
            print('         /|\  | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('      ________|_')
            return
        if index==3:
            clear()
            print('          _____ ')
            print('          |   | ')
            print('          O   | ')
            print('         /|   | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('      ________|_')
            return
        if index==4:
            clear()
            print('          _____ ')
            print('          |   | ')
            print('          O   | ')
            print('          |   | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('      ________|_')
            return
        if index==5:
            clear()
            print('          _____ ')
            print('          |   | ')
            print('          O   | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('      ________|_')
            return
        if index==6:
            clear()
            print('          _____ ')
            print('          |   | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('      ________|_')
            return
        if index==7:
            clear()
            print('          _____ ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('      ________|_')
            return
        if index==8:
            clear()
            print('                ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('              | ')
            print('      ________|_')
            return
        if index==9:
            clear()
            print('                ')
            print('                ')
            print('                ')
            print('                ')
            print('                ')
            print('                ')
            print('      ________|_')
            return

##########################################  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: consider accepting an answer if you found it helpful

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this loop:

```
while True:
    play_game(hangman_word)

    if play_again() == 2:
        return False
        break
    else:
        hangman_word = generate_random()            
        play_game(hangman_word)
```

This loops starts and ends with `play_game(...)`, so you make the user play two games without asking for input inbetween. One call to `play_game` is enough.

Comment: Thanks I dunno how I missed that! appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
def main():
    hangman_word = generate_random()
    while True:
        play_game(hangman_word)

        if play_again() == 2:
            return False
            break
        else:
            hangman_word = generate_random()            
            play_game(hangman_word)
```

Try this:

```
def main():
    while True:
        hangman_word = generate_random() ## get ONE word
        play_game(hangman_word)          ## play ONE game

        if play_again() == 2:  ## if user doesn't want to play anymore, quit
            break ## you could also return False,
            ## just don't do both because only one will be called
```

What you're doing in the original:
When `main()` is first called, you've played zero games.
At the first `play_game(...)` directly under `while True:`, you're playing your first game (Game 1).  After that, if `play_again()` is 1, you're playing your second hangman game (under the `else:` clause).  After both of those games, you loop back to the top and play the game under `while True:` again.

In effect, the original can only play an odd number of games (1, 3, 5, 7, ...).

Comment: Thanks I dunno how I missed that! appreciate your help